# Is there an API for passwordcard.org?

Tags: api, passwords

I'm looking to create a mobile version of the images created on [passwordcard.org](http://www.passwordcard.org/).  All attribution will be given to the site for the data, but I'm looking to implement it where an app doesn't exist yet and network connectivity isn't guaranteed.  Is there an externally accessible API available?  I didn't really see any information about it in the FAQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the creator of passwordcard.org. There is no API, but there is a description of the algorithm used to create the cards so that you can implement it yourself and create the exact same cards as the site would create for the same card numbers. You can find it at http://www.passwordcard.org/algorithm.html